# Obtener resultado especifico dentro de un array

Tags: php, array

Deseo obtener los **id** que se encuentran dentro de este **array** :

```
Array ( 
[count] => 386 
[items] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 293259195 [first_name] => Ana [last_name] => Nidegger ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 320180374 [first_name] => David [last_name] => Gomariz )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 200727184 [first_name] => Piet [last_name] => Mondrian ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 112780770 [first_name] => Victor [last_name] => Gini )
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 170239828 [first_name] => Angelo [last_name] => Santana )
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 316175174 [first_name] => Mhelyssa [last_name] => Vazquez ) 
    [6] => Array ( [id] => 185581600 [first_name] => Diego [last_name] => Pascal ) 
    [7] => Array ( [id] => 167767182 [first_name] => Mario [last_name] => Sith ) 
    [8] => Array ( [id] => 170574351 [first_name] => Micromago [last_name] => Micromago )
    [9] => Array ( [id] => 216820978 [first_name] => Benicio [last_name] => Della-Cabra ) 
) )
```

Lo que me gustaría obtener son todos los id **id = 200727184** y almacenarlos en una variable e usado :

```
$contenido = "";
foreach($arrayLineas as $id){
$contenido .= $id."\n";
}
```

Pero no logro ningún resultado espero me podáis dar alguna idea .

Comment: Sería algo como: **`foreach($arrayLineas["items"] as $row){
$contenido .= $row["id"]."\n";
}`**. Debes acceder al array que se encuentra en `items`, suponiendo que `$arrayLineas` es el objeto completo. Si es ya el array que hay en `items`entonces sería así: **`foreach($arrayLineas as $row){
$contenido .= $row["id"]."\n";
}`**. La cuestión es que en cada fila debes buscar su clave `id`, lo cual no estás haciendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Si `$arrayLineas` es el objeto completo

Tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
$contenido="";
foreach($arrayLineas["items"] as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row["id"].PHP_EOL; 
}
```

#### Si `$arrayLineas` es el array que hay en la clave `items`

```
$contenido="";
foreach($arrayLineas as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row["id"].PHP_EOL; 
}
```

La cuestión es que en cada fila debes buscar su clave `id`, lo cual no estás haciendo.

Nótese que he preferido `PHP_EOL` a `\n`. Es compatible en todas las plataformas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta igual me a quedado una duda si el array es de esta manera  : Array ( [id] => 784512584 )  foreach no funciona igual

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions si es un array con un sólo grupo de elementos puedes obtener el valor de la clave `id` de este modo: **`$tuArray["id"];`** Si es diferente debes poner un ejemplo más completo para saber cómo leerlo o plantearlo en una pregunta distinta.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano lo pondré en practica

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `array_column()` para obtener todos los datos de una columna en este caso **id**, básicamente le pasamos el Array de los items y le indicamos la columna que quieres obtener, esto devuelve un Array con todos los elementos de la columna indicada.

Ejemplo

```
$array = Array ( 
'count' => 386,
'items' => Array ( 
    0 => Array ( 'id' => 293259195, 'first_name' => 'Ana', 'last_name' => 'Nidegger' ),
    1=> Array ( 'id'=> 320180374, 'first_name' => 'David', 'last_name' => 'Gomariz' )
));

$ids = array_column($array ['items'], 'id');
print_r($ids);
```

Resultado

```
  Array ( [0] => 293259195 [1] => 320180374 )
```

Para mostrar el listado uno tras otro simplemente puedes hacer un `implode()`

```
echo implode($ids, ', ');
// 293259195, 320180374
```

Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php

---

Dado el interes de A.Cedano en esta respuesta y la rapidez entre una u otra, paso a dejar el ejemplo utilizado para medir el tiempo de ejecución entre su ejemplo y el mio.

Se a trabajado con un array de 300 items como el siguiente:

```
<?php
$array = Array ( 
    'count' => 386,
    'items' => Array()
);
// esta línea se repetira 300 veces para ambos ejemplos
// solo lo pongo una vez para no ensuciar la respuesta
$array['items'][] = Array ( 'id'=> 320180374, 'first_name' => 'David', 'last_name' => 'Gomariz' );
```

Para el ejemplo del foreach hemos utilizado el siguiente script 10 veces

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
foreach($array["items"] as $row){ 
    echo $row["id"].', '; 
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$t = $time_end - $time_start;
echo '<br>';
echo 'Tiempo: '.number_format($t, 10);
```

Para elejemplo de array_column se ha ejecutado este ejemplo otras 10 veces

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
echo implode(array_column($array['items'], 'id'), ', ');
$time_end = microtime(true);
$t = $time_end - $time_start;
echo '<br>';
echo 'Tiempo: '.number_format($t, 10);
```

Resultados:

```
Resultados foreach
0.0000901222
0.0001010895
0.0001621246
0.0000991821
0.0000610352
0.0001089573
0.0000920296
0.0000650883
0.0001289845
0.0000991821

máximo: 0.0001621246
mínimo: 0.0000610352

Resultados array_column
0.0000419617
0.0000500679
0.0000529289
0.0000610352
0.0000579357
0.0000460148
0.0000600815
0.0000398159
0.0000641346
0.0000619888

máximo: 0.0000641346
mínimo: 0.0000398159
```

Comment: ¿Podrías justificar por qué sugieres esta solución en vez de un procedimiento *natural* para leer una array como lo es `foreach`? Por ejemplo, ¿qué impacto tendría en cuanto al rendimiento el uso de dos funciones: `array_column` e `implode` comparado con un `foreach`?

Comment: @A.Cedano En este caso el op no especifica si quiere mostrar directamente los resultados, solo manifiesta que quiere almacenarlos en una nueva variable, Para este caso es mas limpio y legible/entendible `array_column` y tecnicamente aunque despreciable, mas rapido que un `foreach` ya que no tiene que modificar el puntero interno del array, puedes hacer una prueba de concepto para verificarlo o si quieres te puedo crear un ejemplo para demostrarlo. Por lo general casi todas las funciones nativas suelen ser mas rapidas que un `foreach`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. No estoy seguro de lo que afirmas y siempre he interpretado que lo más rápido para leer arrays es `foreach`. Además, una vez usado `array_column`, vas a tener que invocar a  `implode`. En cuanto al puntero, desde PHP 7 `foreach` no usa el puntero interno del array, [según afirma el Manual en la sección **Notas**](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @A.Cedano He hecho algunas pruebas, mas que nada para salir de dudas, y puedo afirmar que este ejercicio (con array 300 items y PHP7.1.2) es mas rapido con `array_column()` con incluido `implode()`. Es cierto que la diferencia es despreciable ya que se reduce a microsegundos, por lo que es irrelevante el uso de un método u otro. En cuanto al funcionamiento interno de `foreach` es algo mas complejo y puede ser interesante este hilo: https://code-examples.net/es/q/9977c7  Un saludo.

Comment: @A.Cedano a modo de ejercicio y curiosidad he dejado un ejemplo de comparación, ha sido corrido en un servidor de pruebas en local, bajo ubuntu con PHP7.1 y Apache, por si en un momento dado lo quieres replicar.

Comment: Si es como dices y viendo las pruebas entonces te doy la razón. Yo creía que con `foreach` era más rápido. Gracias por la aclaración.